# How to select all groups of intersecting polygons from a single table using PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, gis, postgis

Given a table of groups of intersecting polygons as shown.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlXs1.png) How can we select all the groups of polygons that intersect?

The following query, using recursion, gets some of the way there but it duplicates all the groups and groups with multiple overlaps duplicate polygons within the group.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (

     SELECT id AS root_id,
            id, ARRAY[id] AS path,
            geom
       FROM polygons

      UNION ALL
     SELECT cte.root_id,
            t.id, path || t.id,
            t.geom
       FROM polygons AS t,
            cte
      WHERE t.id <> ALL(cte.path)
        AND ST_Intersects(t.geom, cte.geom) 
)

SELECT root_id, ARRAY_AG(id)
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY root_id
 ORDER BY root_id
```

The resulting selection looks like this:

| root_id | array_agg |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2 |
| 2 | 2,1 |
| 3 | 3,4,5,6 |
| 4 | 4,3,5,6 |
| 5 | 5,4,6,3 |
| 6 | 6,5,4,3 |
| 7 | 7,8,9,9,8 |
| 8 | 8,7,9,9,7 |
| 9 | 9,7,8,8,7 |
| 10 | 10 |

As you will notice, selections with `root_id` 1 and 2 contain the same polygons and `root_id` 7, 8 and 9 all duplicate polygons within the group.

Comment: Use `st_clusterDBScan` with a distance of 0, as shown here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408695/compound-contiguous-links-to-lines-in-a-network-and-find-isolated-lines

Comment: This answers the question, thank you.

Comment: There's a function for exactly that, named extactly like that [`ST_ClusterIntersectingWin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterIntersectingWin.html). Added in PostGIS 3.4.0. In 2.2.0 there's a bit more clunky [`ST_ClusterIntersecting()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterIntersecting.html) that's spitting out collections

Comment: You could just add something like rootid< t.id to the where clause to remove the duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a function for exactly that, named exactly like that: [`ST_ClusterIntersectingWin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterIntersectingWin.html). Added in PostGIS 3.4.0.
[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/yL_xwSLN)

[image]

```sql
explain analyze verbose 
create table my_shapes_clustered2 as
select 1+ST_ClusterIntersectingWin(geom)over() as cluster_number, *
from my_shapes;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| WindowAgg (cost=0.00..15091.00 rows=1200 width=391) (actual time=5.639..5.948 rows=1200 loops=1) |
| Output: (1 + st_clusterintersectingwin(geom) OVER (?)), id, initial_seed, geom |
| -> Seq Scan on public.my_shapes (cost=0.00..76.00 rows=1200 width=387) (actual time=0.006..0.215 rows=1200 loops=1) |
| Output: geom, id, initial_seed |
| Planning Time: 0.063 ms |
| Execution Time: 8.455 ms |

Inspecting some samples:

```sql
select cluster_number,st_area(st_union(geom)),count(*),array_agg(id)
from my_shapes_clustered2 
group by cluster_number 
order by cluster_number 
limit 8;
```

| cluster_number | st_area | count | array_agg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 836.248837776196 | 2 | {798,1} |
| 2 | 651.4061064388445 | 1 | {2} |
| 3 | 53.56050595625381 | 1 | {3} |
| 4 | 269.4408305746047 | 1 | {4} |
| 5 | 1596.5821681225993 | 4 | {507,5,676,72} |
| 6 | 1262.1100035153077 | 3 | {186,296,6} |
| 7 | 2008.7632476757103 | 4 | {474,891,7,1121} |
| 8 | 66.289777695502 | 1 | {8} |

In PostGIS 2.3.0+ you can get the same result, although slightly slower, using the [`ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom,0,1)`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) function [suggested by @JGH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78227076/how-to-select-all-groups-of-intersecting-polygons-from-a-single-table-using-post#comment137912407_78227076):

```sql
explain analyze verbose 
create table my_shapes_clustered3 as
select 1+ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom,0,1)over() as cluster_number, *
from my_shapes;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| WindowAgg (cost=0.00..15091.00 rows=1200 width=391) (actual time=17.688..18.018 rows=1200 loops=1) |
| Output: (1 + st_clusterdbscan(geom, '0'::double precision, 1) OVER (?)), id, initial_seed, geom |
| -> Seq Scan on public.my_shapes (cost=0.00..76.00 rows=1200 width=387) (actual time=0.005..0.218 rows=1200 loops=1) |
| Output: geom, id, initial_seed |
| Planning Time: 0.041 ms |
| Execution Time: 21.007 ms |

In 2.2.0 there's a bit more clunky `ST_ClusterIntersecting()` that's spitting out collections.